# What is Happening inside the useRef here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-ref

I'm creating a Slider with react.js.
I need to call the **nextSlide** function automatically here. So, I used the useEffect hook.
I got a code like this

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length;
  const timeout = useRef(null);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const nextSlide = () =>
      setCurrent((prevState) => (prevState === length - 1 ? 0 : prevState + 1));
    timeout.current = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);
    return function () {
      if (timeout.current) {
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
      }
    };
  }, [current, length]);
```

But I'm confused about what is happening inside.
how did **useRef** hook help in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't. It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`useRef` returns the same object across rerenders, so in general it can be used to store values in a way that they can be retrieved inside callbacks and always reflect the latest value. Now in your case this is not necessary, as you want to refer to the timer inside of the *effects cleanup*, and as that's an inner function of the *effect*, you can just refer to it's variables:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   // ...
   const timer = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);

   return function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
   };
 }, [length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the js code

```
function foo(){
    let x = 1;
    console.log(x++);
} 

foo();
foo();
```

Here the output is `1 1` not `1 2` because for each call it creates a new scope in which the value of x is initially set to 1. Modification of a variable in a scope doesn't affect the other.

React functional components are simple javascript functions. React responds to a state change in the functional component by calling the function again.

If you had used the following syntax instead of **useRef**

```
const MyComponent = ()=>{
     const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
     let timeout = null;
     ...
}
```

the value of `timeout` will reset to null whenever you call `setCurrent`. Because react will call the function again to get the updated output. So the function will lose control of the timer and will show unexpected behaviour.

`useRef()` will not return a variable but a reference to a variable/memory location outside the function's scope. So for each call, the function variable is not recreated but its reference is used.

For `const timeout = useRef(null)` timeout is the reference and its current value can be obtained using `ti

**Alternative Solution**

Declaring the timeout variable outside component is also a solution.

```
let timeout = null;
const MyComponent = ()=>{
     const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
     ...
}
```